# ngModel ignores placeholders

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angularfire2

When i try to add this:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let rg of reg | async">
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="rg.key" placeholder="{{rg.b}}"></ion-input>
</ion-row>
```

It highlights `rg.key` value with active color `#000` insted of `placeholders` value.

But if i replace the variable with `something else` it works:

```
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="somethingelse" placeholder="{{rg.b}}"></ion-input>
```

Can anybody help me to fix this?

[**Stackblitz link here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wpcjkd)

Comment: can you create a stackblitz demo

Comment: I have to add full code for this because it's a problem with calling a value by variable in `ngModel`

Comment: can you post the array

Comment: `this.reg = this.db.list('firebase/info').valueChanges()` providing the array for `reg: Observable<any[]>;`

Comment: post the array not the code

Comment: I didn't get you. Firebase database directly providing array data and input tags will depend on firebase data length.  I am yet to set array to get the input data which can be done later if can fix this problem. There is no problem with array data provider.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160345/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-user3449848).

Answer (score 0):

`Placeholders` are shown when the value they are pointing at doesn't exists (or `undefined` in our case).

Replace the following line:

```
reg = [{num: 201}, {num: 202}];
```

To:

```
reg = [{num: undefined}, {num: 202}];
```

Now you will see that for the first `reg` iteration, the `placeholder` will replace the `undefined` value (but it doesn't replace the `201` value).

This applies to your other code (which is not in the snippet)

```
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="rg.key" placeholder="{{rg.b}}"></ion-input>
```

Only when the value `eg.key` is undefined, you will notice the placeholder `rg.b`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Can i get `ngModel` data in array? Like: to get data from `<div *ngFor="let rg of reg; let i = index"> <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="ab as rg.key" placeholder="{{rg.b}}"></ion-input> </div>` and in ts file  `ab = []` possible?

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean...can you try to explain yourself?

Comment: I have changed my coding structure because it won't work for me.Thanks anyway